# Cannot locate where google font is loaded insecurely

Tags: joomla-3.x, ssl

I'm implementing SSL on a Joomla/Virtuemart site and have a google font file being loaded insecurely. I have searched through the site files and cannot find any reference to it, nor when i search for the reference on the landing page where it is flagged up, can i find it - its extremely odd.

The site is (edited out)

The file being called insecurely is: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700

But searching in the elements tab of dev tools, there is no reference to 'oxygen' nor 'http://fonts' - I'm at a loss as to where this is being loaded from.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance
Donna

Comment: check your template.  Specifically the index.php or a file that generates the <head> section.  Also search for gstatic.

Comment: I've inspected the source and there's no reference to "oxygen". Are you sure you've provided the correct website URL?

Comment: @Lodder Absolutely - if you look at the console window it is showing it as mixed content for loading the link over http. I'm baffled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeez this template need some serious updating.

Anyway I found the code:

> https://www.example.com/templates/ot_tshirt/assets/css/custom.css

and at the very top of the file, you'll see this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i know, its a legacy site which I'm working on updating for a customer (not built by myself). Jeez, I clearly couldn't see the woods for the trees on this one - I've searched everywhere for this. Thanks for pointing it out :)